# PingFederate error - Ignoring attempt to add null value to attribute map for USER_KEY

Tags: openid-connect, pingfederate

We have a PF installation, in which we are trying to setup OpenID Connect based SSO. We have the PF IdP connected to our internal Windows AD. When we try to request an Auth Code, to perform a Browser-based SSO, we get this exception:
 `Mapping into unique user key resulted in null or empty value from source attributes`

This is what is present in the log file

```
2016-04-26 10:42:26,912 tid:uWXoT4raO7G-Cx8LMtl6ioqtvuI DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.domain.LDAPUsernamePasswordCredentialValidator] search sAMAccountName=MYLOGIN
2016-04-26 10:42:26,912 tid:uWXoT4raO7G-Cx8LMtl6ioqtvuI DEBUG [org.sourceid.servlet.HttpServletRespProxy] adding lazy cookie Cookie{PF=v15OJ5PwavFr0TTQqGGPxWrOjzUTXlkVKfVCB2yceOXN; path=/; maxAge=-1; domain=null} replacing Cookie{PF=v15OJ5PwavFr0TTQqGGPxWv76zVxxdpyURw82xJJBtXK; path=/; maxAge=-1; domain=null}
2016-04-26 10:42:26,912 tid:uWXoT4raO7G-Cx8LMtl6ioqtvuI DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.grouprpc.PreferredNodes] [] -> indices to addresses -> [IP1, IP2]
2016-04-26 10:42:26,912  DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.localmemory.InterReqStateMgmtMapImpl] setAttr(oldKey: v76zVxxdpyURw82xJJBtXK, newKey: rOjzUTXlkVKfVCB2yceOXN, name: HtmlFormIdpAuthnAdapter:WatsonHTML:SESSION)
2016-04-26 10:42:26,912  DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.localmemory.InterReqStateMgmtMapImpl] setAttr: new size of attribute map=110
2016-04-26 10:42:26,912  DEBUG [com.pingidentity.jgroups.MuxInvocationHandler] invocation of setAttr on InterReqStateMgmtMapImpl state map size:8 attributes map size110
2016-04-26 10:42:26,912 tid:uWXoT4raO7G-Cx8LMtl6ioqtvuI DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.grouprpc.InterRequestStateMgmtGroupRpcImpl] called mode:GET_MAJORITY setAttr() on [IP1, IP2]
2016-04-26 10:42:26,912 tid:uWXoT4raO7G-Cx8LMtl6ioqtvuI DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.grouprpc.PreferredNodes] [] -> indices to addresses -> [IP1, IP2]
2016-04-26 10:42:26,912  DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.localmemory.InterReqStateMgmtMapImpl] setAttr(oldKey: rOjzUTXlkVKfVCB2yceOXN, newKey: rOjzUTXlkVKfVCB2yceOXN, name: HtmlFormIdpAuthnAdapter:WatsonHTML:last-activity)
2016-04-26 10:42:26,912  DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.localmemory.InterReqStateMgmtMapImpl] setAttr: new size of attribute map=110
2016-04-26 10:42:26,912  DEBUG [com.pingidentity.jgroups.MuxInvocationHandler] invocation of setAttr on InterReqStateMgmtMapImpl state map size:8 attributes map size110
2016-04-26 10:42:26,912 tid:uWXoT4raO7G-Cx8LMtl6ioqtvuI DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.grouprpc.InterRequestStateMgmtGroupRpcImpl] called mode:GET_MAJORITY setAttr() on [IP1, IP2]
2016-04-26 10:42:26,912 tid:uWXoT4raO7G-Cx8LMtl6ioqtvuI DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.grouprpc.PreferredNodes] [] -> indices to addresses -> [IP1, IP2]
2016-04-26 10:42:26,912  DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.localmemory.InterReqStateMgmtMapImpl] setAttr(oldKey: rOjzUTXlkVKfVCB2yceOXN, newKey: rOjzUTXlkVKfVCB2yceOXN, name: HtmlFormIdpAuthnAdapter:WatsonHTML:first-activity)
2016-04-26 10:42:26,912  DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.localmemory.InterReqStateMgmtMapImpl] setAttr: new size of attribute map=110
2016-04-26 10:42:26,912  DEBUG [com.pingidentity.jgroups.MuxInvocationHandler] invocation of setAttr on InterReqStateMgmtMapImpl state map size:8 attributes map size110
2016-04-26 10:42:26,912 tid:uWXoT4raO7G-Cx8LMtl6ioqtvuI DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.grouprpc.InterRequestStateMgmtGroupRpcImpl] called mode:GET_MAJORITY setAttr() on [IP1, IP2]
2016-04-26 10:42:26,912 tid:uWXoT4raO7G-Cx8LMtl6ioqtvuI DEBUG [org.sourceid.servlet.HttpServletRespProxy] adding lazy cookie Cookie{pf-hfa-WatsonHTML-rmu=; path=/; maxAge=0; domain=null} replacing null
2016-04-26 10:42:26,912 tid:uWXoT4raO7G-Cx8LMtl6ioqtvuI DEBUG [org.sourceid.websso.authn.AdapterAuthnProcessor] adapterResponse=SUCCESS
2016-04-26 10:42:26,912 tid:uWXoT4raO7G-Cx8LMtl6ioqtvuI DEBUG [org.sourceid.util.log.AttributeMap] Ignoring attempt to add null value to attribute map for context.TargetResource
2016-04-26 10:42:26,912 tid:uWXoT4raO7G-Cx8LMtl6ioqtvuI DEBUG [org.sourceid.util.log.AttributeMap] Ignoring attempt to add null value to attribute map for USER_KEY
2016-04-26 10:42:26,912 tid:uWXoT4raO7G-Cx8LMtl6ioqtvuI DEBUG [org.sourceid.util.log.AttributeMap] Ignoring attempt to add null value to attribute map for USER_NAME
2016-04-26 10:42:26,912 tid:uWXoT4raO7G-Cx8LMtl6ioqtvuI DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.domain.AttributeMapping] Source attributes:{context.ClientIp=CLIP, context.OAuthScopes=openid, username=MYLOGIN, DN=CN=My Name,OU=Users,OU=xx,OU=xx,DC=xx,DC=yy,DC=co,DC=uk, org.sourceid.saml20.adapter.idp.authn.authnInst=1461663746912, context.ClientId=UAT-Watson, context.HttpRequest=/as/Z3XeL/resume/as/authorization.ping} Resulting attributes:{}
2016-04-26 10:42:26,912 tid:uWXoT4raO7G-Cx8LMtl6ioqtvuI ERROR [org.sourceid.oauth20.handlers.HandleAuthorizationRequest] Exception occurred during request processing
org.sourceid.websso.profiles.ProcessRuntimeException: Mapping into unique user key resulted in null or empty value from source attributes
    at org.sourceid.oauth20.domain.UserKeyAttrMapping.execMapping(UserKeyAttrMapping.java:50) ~[pf-protocolengine.jar:?]
    at org.sourceid.oauth20.domain.UserKeyAttrMapping.execMapping(UserKeyAttrMapping.java:38) ~[pf-protocolengine.jar:?]
```

I am confused on why it is getting NULL values for USER_KEY and USER_NAME, inspite of the IdP adapter reponse being SUCCESS.

Can someone help?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. I found the fix. In my IdP adapter mapping, I had `USER_NAME` mapped to  `displayName` from `Adapter`. I changed it to the `Text` value of `${username}`. This helped. But, still dont understand how/why this is the right thing to do.

Comment: Where was displayName coming from? Did it have a value? I ask, because I don't see it set to anything in the log snippet...

Comment: I am getting it from HTML form adapter, which is pulling it from AD. I can't really say for sure if it had a value. I presumed so

Comment: Run an LDAP search. I don't see a value returned from the adapter in your log snippet.